# How to use @Scope in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I read a lot of material on the @Scope annotation but still not fully understanding if what I know is correct.

Can someone explain what exactly is @Scope for? Where is it used? How is it used?

Is it only used when defining the component?

Also is a scope defined like this?:

```
@Scope
public @interface SomeScope {
}
```

And used like this?:

```
@SomeScope
@Component(modules = {
        HeaterModule.class,
        PumpModule.class
})
public interface MainActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    CoffeeMaker maker();
}
```

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397211/dagger2-what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-a-scope-tag-to-components) is still close to the top of the list of questions tagged `dagger-2`.  The accepted answer is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of scopes for Java EE applications states the following:

> For a web application to use a bean that injects another bean class,
>   the bean needs to be able to hold state over the duration of the
>   user’s interaction with the application. The way to define this state
>   is to give the bean a scope.

Let's associate it with Android. Scopes impose certain limitations in terms of dependencies lifecycle provided by a scoped provider.

For example, let's say we want to be provided with `@Singleton` dependency obtainable from `@ActivityScope`d component. The component lives as long as the Activity. Once activity is destroyed and created again, our component is instantiated accordingly and our '@Singleton' dependency is also created once again.

Summing up, our `@Singleton` dependencies live as long as the `@Components` they are associated with - this is I think most practical explanation.

Internally, once Dagger notifies within the `@Component` the provision method with the specified scope, it creates a [ScopedProvider](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/internal/ScopedProvider.html) for dependency provision. Otherwise, a [Factory](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/internal/Factory.html) is created.

The `ScopedProvider`'s get method is a double-check singleton method:

```
public T get() {
    // double-check idiom from EJ2: Item 71
    Object result = instance;
    if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
      synchronized (this) {
        result = instance;
        if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
          instance = result = factory.get();
        }
      }
    }
    return (T) result;
  }
```

To see a practical `@Scope` usage you can take a look at one of the examples of mine:

https://github.com/dawidgdanski/AccountAuthenticatorExample

Hope, that was helpful somehow.

**EDIT 1**:
The article provided by @Fshamri explains it even better.

**EDIT 2**:

Let's consider the following structure :

The Component:

```
@ActivityScope //Dagger ignores the annotation put atop the @Component. I put it there just for readability
@Component(dependencies = DependencyGraph.class,
        modules = {ActivityModule.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(SignUpActivity signUpActivity);
    void inject(SignInActivity signInActivity);
```

And the module supplying the dependencies:

```
    @Module
    public class ActivityModule {

    private final Activity activity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    MainView provideMainView() {
        return (MainView) activity;
    }

    @Provides
    SignInView provideSignInView() {
        return (SignInView) activity;
    }
    }
```

The [@ActivityScope](https://github.com/dawidgdanski/AccountAuthenticatorExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authenticator/account/ui/ActivityScope.java) extends the [@Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Scope.html) annotation - it is interpreted by Dagger the same way as the [@Singleton](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) is. The `ActivityModule` provides 2 views: the `@ActivityScope`d `MainView` and the `SignInView` without any scope. During the compilation time Dagger's annotation processor creates [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html)s for both views. The difference between the MainView's and the SignInView's generated Provider is that for the MainView Dagger generates the `ScopedProvider` (because we explicitly request this kind of provider with `@ActivityScope`) whereas for the `SignInView` Dagger generates regular `Factory` provider.

The contract of the ScopedProvider looks like the one above. The contract for the `Factory` provider, however, looks the following way:

```
@Generated("dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor")
public final class ActivityModule_ProvideSignInViewFactory implements Factory<SignInView> {
  private final ActivityModule module;

  public ActivityModule_ProvideSignInViewFactory(ActivityModule module) {  
    assert module != null;
    this.module = module;
  }
  @Override
  public SignInView get() {  
    SignInView provided = module.provideSignInView();
    if (provided == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method");
    }
    return provided;
  }

  public static Factory<SignInView> create(ActivityModule module) {  
    return new ActivityModule_ProvideSignInViewFactory(module);
  }
}
```

Conclusions:
1. The `ScopedProvider` is a classical double-check singleton pattern. It guarantees to create only one instance of the dependency.
2. The `Factory`'s `get()` method just distributes the dependency from the module which means it can distribute new instance of the dependency each time it is requested (in fact, in the example the Activity is only cast to the SignInView which still gives us a single instance but this is copy-pasted logic from my example).
3. Dagger cares about @Scopes provided along with provision methods in the @Modules, not the @Components.

I encourage you to download the sample and build the project, then to see the contract of the generated `Dagger` components and modules.

Hope this is more understandable now.

Comment: Thank you! Your example was clean and simple, it helped me connect the dots once you said the "@Singleton dependency exists as long as the Component associated with it exists." If I do not use the "@Scoped" annotation at the top of the "@Component" then does that mean the singleton will exist even if the activity is terminated?

Comment: Please, read the "EDIT 2" explanation. Dagger ignores any Scope-inherited annotations put in Component's definition.

Comment: @Rayx I wasn't correct by saying that Dagger ignores Scope-inherited annotation in Component's definition. It actually requires them if they are independent from the main application's component.

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at [this article](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/)?

> In Dagger 2 scopes mechanism cares about keeping single instance of
>   class as long as its scope exists. In practice it means that instances
>   scoped in @ApplicationScope lives as long as Application object.
>   @ActivityScope keeps references as long as Activity exists (for
>   example we can share single instance of any class between all
>   fragments hosted in this Activity). In short - scopes give us “local
>   singletons” which live as long as scope itself.